# repeat a component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Is there a way i can repeat a component, something like:

```
<Apex:repeat value="{!object}" var="tr">
  <c:component componentattr={!object}/>
  <apex:outputText value="{!tr}"/><br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use your example Visualforce markup? Are you running into any errors?

Comment: @DerekF, which markups. I can only find <apex:page controller.. what i want to do is get a list from a controller into a visualforce email template where apex pagecontroller is not supported

Comment: I mean the exact markup that you used as an example in your question. If you can repeat using a component, what you've included in your question looks very close to what you'd actually need to do. Since you already seem to know what the possible answer would look like, I was asking if you had actually tried what you've worked out so far. Trying something for yourself, after all, is faster than waiting for other people to try it for you.

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to include more details. Generically speaking, you can use components in iterators just like you'd be able to use almost any other type of element in an iterator. There's nothing "wrong" with what you've done here that I can see, except perhaps that the initial element is `Apex:repeat` but instead should be `apex:repeat`. Visualforce is XML-based, so some things might break if you don't use proper casing.

Comment: You say you've already tried the example markup that you included and that it doesn't work. Please go into more detail about what exactly isn't working. Are you getting an error? If not, are you seeing any output? If the output isn't what you are expecting, can you go into more detail about what output you _are_ expecting?